# How to ng-repeat over an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Very simple question, I've Googled but the results were vague to to and felt like it didn't apply to me...

In my html I can access an *artists name* like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{hypedArtists.artist[0].name}}</li>
    <li>{{hypedArtists.artist[1].name}}</li>
    <li>{{hypedArtists.artist[2].name}}</li>
</ul>
```

It gets the right data but hardcoding it like that isn't right, obviously. How can I use ng-repeat to itterate over *hypedArtists.artist* to get each artists name and populate my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in hypedArtists.artist">{{artist.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

For reference: [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Ah man... I did, but what I said was 'artist in hypedArtists' and not 'artist in hypedArtists.artist'.. Thank you :)

Comment: Yep, the array contains the `artist` from `hypedArtists`: `hypedArtists.artist[i]`.